# DAX running total calendar date issue with IF statement

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dax, cumulative-sum

I have a simple if statement for calculating values on date

```
IF statement = 
IF(AND(MAX('Calendar'[Date]) > [Last date], SUM('Calendar'[Value1]) > COUNT('Value2'[Value2])), [diff_e_2],
 IF(AND(MAX('Calendar'[Date]) > [Last date], SUM('Calendar'[Value1]) < COUNT('Value2'[Value2])), [diff_t_2],
  IF(MAX('Calendar'[Date]) < [Last date], [diff_t_2],
     IF(MAX('Calendar'[Date]) = [Last date], [diff_e_2](), 
[diff_e_2])
)))
```

[Last date] = TODAY() + 10

This is working fine and I can get the graph I want. But when I create a running/cumulative total it doesn't work on the date [Last date].

```
Running total = 
CALCULATE(([IF statement]), FILTER(ALLSELECTED('Calendar'), 'Calendar'[Date]<=MAX('Calendar'[Date])))
```

Otherwise it works but in this case [Last date] should add 0 but instead it is deducting 2. And most times it is deducting values and can't find the reason.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Br,
Joona

Answer (score 0):

You formula for the running total is quite incorrect, supposing your if statement return value instead of string, then the formula correction should be working, else you are trying to calculate string which will cause error in measure:

```
Running total = 
CALCULATE(([IF statement]), FILTER(ALLSELECTED('Calendar'), 'Calendar'[Date]<=MAX('Calendar'[Date])))
```

Should be:

```
Running total = 
CALCULATE(sum([IF statement]), FILTER(ALL('Calendar'), 'Calendar'[Date]<=MAX('Calendar'[Date])))
```

It will be better to include a sample of your data in case the correction of formula still not working :)